# UNION, SUM and count(*) together in PHP SQL query

Tags: mysql, count, sum, union

So I have php SQL query that queries the floors and the total workstations on each floor.

```
config_location_workstation  workstation          asset_inventory

floor                        floor                floor
workstation_number           workstation_number   workstation_number
workstation_name             assigned_user
(production|non-production)  machine_type
```

I have config_location_workstation table that consist of floor, workstation_number, workstation_name (Production, Non-Production).

Then, I have asset_workstation table that consist of floor, workstation_number, assigned_user, machine_type (Laptop, Desktop). workstation_number has all the users workstation number per floor.

I also have asset_inventory table that also has floor and workstation_number of each machine.

I was able to query the total count of workstations per floor. But I also need to pull up all the workstation_name that has 'Production' in it. I need to combine all the tables to produce one query to get the total count of each workstation, machines deployed to each floor, total head count per floor. I need to get the count of all users workstation number per workstation_name (Production, Non-Production).

This is the current code I have to pull up the floors and the total workstations.

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT workstation.floor, COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM ( SELECT floor FROM config_location_workstation UNION ALL SELECT floor FROM asset_workstation ) AS workstation GROUP BY floor ORDER BY floor");
```

I am expecting to output

```
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| Floor | Head Count  | Workstations| Machines Deployed |
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| 6TH   | 100         | 150         | 140               |
| 18TH  | 200         | 250         | 200               |
| 19TH  | 300         | 320         | 310               |
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

How am I going to do this in one query.

Comment: looking at the workstation name will break your count(*) grouping. Please expand your expected output to show how you want the extra data to be built

Comment: Before you start trying to write a query, make sure you have a good, normalized set of tables to work with.  Your problem is not the creation of a query; it’s “I don’t have enough idea how I can combine all of it in one table”.  What will help immensely is to edit your question and include the schema of your table(s). When that part is right, the query is much easier

Comment: Hi @TimMorton, can you check it now? I have edited my questions and provided the tables I have.

Comment: @gordon, I have expanded the outputs now. thanks for checking.

Comment: Learning proper database design will be a good start.  In a glance, it seems like the same columns appear in multiple tables.  That's really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables are not normalized:  there appears to be duplicate information in all 3 tables. (unless workstation_number is not unique and floor/workstation_number is a composite key.  I would advise against that...)

I would suggest a schema similar to this (assuming a many-to-many relationship between users and workstations):

```
Workstation              User_Workstation     User
id                 <- -  workstation_id     
workstation_number       user_id         - -> id
machine_type                                  name
name
floor
```

Each of the fields in `Workstation` describe an attribute of a workstation.  Any information you may have gathered from the other two tables is now in one place.  ***Don't Repeat Yourself!*** Duplicate data is *evil*.

The goal is

> I need to combine all the tables to produce one query to get the
>
> - total count of each workstation,
> - machines deployed to each floor,
> - total head count per floor.
> - I need to get the count of all users workstation number per workstation_name (Production, Non-Production).

Individually, these are a piece of cake.  (And, if you're running a script to get your results, it's all you need)

```
select count(id) number_of_workstations
from Workstation;

select count(id) workstations_per_floor, floor
from Workstation
group by floor

select count(u.id) users_per_floor, floor
from Workstation w
inner join User_Workstation uw on w.id = uw.workstation_id
inner join User u on u.id = uw.user_id
-- optionally filter by production or non-production
-- where w.name = ?
group by w.floor
```

But your desired result seems to be something different:

```
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| Floor | Head Count  | Workstations| Machines Deployed |
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| 6TH   | 100         | 150         | 140               |
| 18TH  | 200         | 250         | 200               |
| 19TH  | 300         | 320         | 310               |
+-------+-------------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

I'm guessing that `Head Count` is number of users per floor, `Workstations` is total workstations per floor, and `Machines Deployed` is... I have no idea.  Production?

```
select floor, count(u.id) Head_Count, count(distinct w.id) Workstations, -- ??? as Machines_Deployed
from workstation w
left join user_workstation uw on w.id = uw.workstation_id
left join user on u.id = uw.user_id
group by w.floor
```

(I'll modify this based on feedback on what `Machines Deployed` is)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Tim Morton. I was able to fix it from another source I reviewed. But this is very informative and I learned a lot from this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  I am curious to see what your solution was.  Feel free to post it as an answer; I might learn something too!